# Problem with AspectRatio in ListPlot

Tags: plotting

```
data = {{-1.77815, -4.92143}, {-1.47712, -4.44227}, {-1.30103, -4.17258},
        {-1.17609, -3.97794}, {-1.07918, -3.84542}};

ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Why is the `AspectRatio` for horizontal and vertical axis not equal?

Comment: thank you ... is a similar command available, so the the axes have 1:1 scaling, without specifying the plot range?

Comment: `AspectRatio -> Full`

Comment: it seems that only `AspectRatio -> Automatic` yields the 1:1 axes scaling, as Thomas answered.

Comment: To verify that`AspectRatio -> Automatic` gives the intended ratio: `(AspectRatio /. (ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
       AspectRatio -> Automatic] // 
      AbsoluteOptions[#, AspectRatio] & // Quiet)) == 
 Subtract @@ MinMax[data[[All, 2]]]/Subtract @@ MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you ... it looks as I wanted ... in the documentation it is written: `AspectRatio -> Automatic` determines the ratio of height to width from the actual coordinate values in the plot. I would like to know what exactly is meant by that ...

Comment: I guess it means exactly what you want to achieve - that the aspect ratio of the plot corresponds to the aspect ratio of the actual coordinates. In other words, x- and y-coordinates are plotted at the same scale

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Thomas works also when when `PlotRange` is used:

```
ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-3, 1}, {-6, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Somebody's system isn't working correctly. For me this shows your original plot with a square area, which is what `AspectRatio->1` should mean.

Comment: @N.J.Evans: sorry mistake: `AspectRatio -> Automatic` should be there ...